# eclipse throws AndroidManifest.xml file missing deployment error, though the file exist

Tags: java, android, c, eclipse

I'm using `eclipse android IDE` (bundle)

a strange thing,
I have build my android application successfully (no errors)

it includes android Apllication project and a native c code project.

I try to run the android project on my android-device

and get this error:

`Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
AndroidManifest.xml file missing!   WazeAndroid     Unknown Android Packaging Problem`

Although I see it in the package tree.

I have googled. tried t restart eclipse and my Mac

nothing helped.

Comment: check this if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12825004/error-androidmanifest-xml-file-missing-what-am-i-missing

Comment: nope. I have a R.java file

Comment: Menu -> Project -> Properties -> Builders -> **Check** `Android Pre Compiler`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AndroidManifest.xml is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525969/androidmanifest-xml-is-missing)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Project in menu and do Clean your project which one you selecting then run your program.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a google offical solution

To fix this problem, simply delete the debug.keystore file. The default storage location for AVDs is in ~/.android/avd on OS X and Linux, in C:\Documents and Settings\.android\ on Windows XP, and in C:\Users\.android\ on Windows Vista.
The next time you build, the build tools will regenerate a new keystore and debug key.

I hope that this can help you.

Comment: I found this answer to a similar question fixed it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15718928/338479