# Intellij idea13.1.2 androidmanifest.xml

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I just started to use intellij idea  Then have tried to create my first application . But something went wrong . The problem was "AndroidManifest.xml doesn't exist or has incorrect root tag " . Thanks All , happy coding ...

Comment: post your androidmanifest.xml file

Comment: I can't see it , and I can't find AndroidManifest.xml in directory .

Comment: possible duplicate of [error: androidmanifest.xml file missing --> What am i missing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12825004/error-androidmanifest-xml-file-missing-what-am-i-missing)